# Tkinter doesn't print on window

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

def quit():
    global root
    root.quit()
def prnt():
    global usrinpt
    lbl = tk.Label(text = usrinpt )
    lbl.pack()




root = tk.Tk()
usrentr = tk.Entry()
usrinpt = str(usrentr.get())
usrentr.pack()
extbt = tk.Button(command=quit,text = 'Exit')
extbt.pack()
lblbt = tk.Button(command = prnt, text = 'Label')
lblbt.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

When I hit the Label button it just extends the window and doesn't print anything.
 Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are calling `usrentr.get()` about a millisecond after you create the entry widget. You need to call it after the user has a chance to type something.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the entry box then instantly trying to get the contents in the subsequent line. You should instead add a "submit" button that has the command set to  star(usrentr.get())

Comment: Changed it, Thanks for the suggestion!